# Javascript detect user upload image width & height not working in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#upload').change(function(){
    var f=this.files[0];

    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var file, img;

    if((file = f)){
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var imgW = this.width;
            var imgH = this.height;

            if(imgW < 150 || imgH < 150){alert(imgW);}
            else{alert('pass');}
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

I have an input file, it can check user's image too small, it works all browser expect Safari 5.1.7(windows version), Mac have higher version, works fine.

I have no idea where went wrong, anyone can find the problem?

Comment: Does Safari give you any errors in the console?

Comment: how can I check console in Safari? I press F12, its not working

Comment: Make sure you have the develop menu: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/safaridevelop.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileAPI isn't fully supported in Safari 5.1.  You probably have use a multiparty form and upload the file because looks like the FileReader piece is missing in safari 5.1

http://caniuse.com/fileapi